# CSS File Selection

Tags: html, css

I need the browser to download the appropriate script for the client browser.
I need some kind of switch statement that would work?

I have ;

- (common.css) All browsers script need this file
- (ie6.css) IE 6 script
- (ie7.css) IE 7 script
- (ie8.css) IE 8 script
- (ie9.css) IE 9 script
- (other.css) Mozilla + Firefox + Safari use the same for all versions

i have (but doesnt work)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IE 6 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[elseif IE 7 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[elseif IE 8 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[elseif IE 9 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie9.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[else]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Q. Ive hacked the above  code from another file but cant get it to work?
If ive got it wrong, is there a better type of switch statement that can be used?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you have to do each condition separately, and not in a switch statement

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css" /> 
   <!--[if IE 6 ]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie9.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

**If not IE**

```
   <!--[if !IE]> -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" type="text/css" />
   <!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: ok thats how I started but I need the other.css file to also be conditional,  so how do I add that in the if statement. My understanding is the html if is a IE thing?

Comment: You need the other file to be conditional based on the browser not being iE?

Comment: Indidnt know I can do <!--[if !IE]> -->, would have been nice if MSFT added a switch control. But thankyou for your help. This did fix the problem .

Comment: Cool cool. It is only logical for an if condition to be true or false

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE 6 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" type="text/css" />
   <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" type="text/css" />
   <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" type="text/css" />
   <![endif]--> 
   <!--[if IE 9 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie9.css" type="text/css" />
   <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks Musa, I have to award the point to RPM as he got in first.